# Are C++ types classes?

Tags: c++, data-types, type

I am trying to understand if C++ types are classes, like in Python for example.

Otherwise what datatype is the type itself? E.g. `int a = 10` what is `int`? Is just a token label used by the compiler to decided the space to allocate to the variable?

Comment: First, you have to decide what are essential traits of a `class`. Skipping that step is an exercise in futility.

Comment: note that C++ has *three* keywords that are used for defining class types: `class`, `struct` and `union`, and uses the keyword `class` in situations beyond declaring and defining classes.

Comment: The relationship is:  All classes are types but not all types are classes.  int is a type, not a class.

Comment: C++ does not have a unified type system.  There is no [base "`Object`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5697373/471129) as there is in Java or C#.  Even two user-defined classes are unrelated in that there is [no common base type](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273306/63202), unlike Java or C#.  There is no attempt to make primitive types like `int` fit into a common class hierarchy, no automatic [boxing and unboxing](https://github.com/AlexWorx/ALib-Boxing).

Comment: @Deduplicator Shall I explain here what is a class in C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A type for a variable in C++ does three main things. First of all it is used to determine the actual amount of memory for a variable. The second thing it does is to determine the operations that are supported for the variable. The third thing it does is to determine how data is transformed from other types to the type of the variable and whether such a transformation is possible.

So an `int` which is a built in type has a certain size that an `int` variable occupies in memory. For a number of historical, backwards compatibility reasons the size of an `int` will vary between different kinds of hardware. On a 16 bit CPU it may be 16 bits, on a 32 bit CPU it may be 32 bits, and on a 64 bit CPU it may be 64 bits. However it is always signed. If you want to specify the size no matter what the hardware you need to use one of the more specific types such as `short` or `long` or `long long`.

An `int` variable also has certain operators and operations that can be used with the variable such as the plus operator (+) for addition and the multiplication operator (*) for multiplication. For an `int` variable these operators are defined to provide specific behaviors just as for a `string` variable they have different behaviors, e.g. the plus operator does string concatenation.

Finally an `int` variable has certain transformations that the compiler will generate for you. If you assign a `float` to an `int` variable then the compiler will transform the value of the `float` into an `int` by truncating any decimal portion of the value. So a floating point value of 3.456 will be truncated to 3 and a floating point value of 0.123 will be truncated to 0.

And the compiler will not allow some types of transformations because those transformations are not defined for an `int`. If you define a class which does not have a method for transforming the class to an `int` and then try to assign a variable of that type to an `int` the compiler will generate an error message.

The word "type" in C++ or C or most languages that use static type variables is a kind of variable classification used by the compiler to help programmers avoid mistakes and to help the compiler allocate memory more efficiently and to generate more efficient machine code.

A type is a way to classify variables. Languages such as JavaScript do not use static type but rather dynamic type. In JavaScript or php the type of a variable will depend on the value last assigned to the variable and the languages do a lot of conversions for you automatically.

In C++, as in C and Java, there are built in types and there are programmer defined types. Variable types such as `int` or `char` are built in types also known as Plain Old Data as these types have direct hardware representations.

A programmer can create defined types in C++ in a number of ways. The most common is by using the `class` keyword or the `struct` keyword to define a class which can then be used as a type when defining variables or functions.

With the new standards, C++11 and later, there is a new keyword `auto` which can be used when defining a variable. This is a way to declare a variable's type by using an expression on the right hand side of the assignment operator to generate a value with a particular type and assign both the value and the type to variable being defined. Once this is done, the variable's type can not be changed however using `auto` can be really helpful.

Comment: "*Variable types such as int or char are built in types also known as Plain Old Data as these types have direct hardware representations.*" They are more correctly known as *fundamental types*. They are POD, but POD represents something else. There can be POD types that don't have "direct hardware representations. And even fundamental types don't *have to* have "direct hardware representations".

Comment: `short`, `long`, and `long long` are not guaranteed to have the same size across different environments. The only guarantees are that `short` is at least as large as `signed char`, `int` is at least as large as `short` *and* is large enough to contain the range `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`, `long` is at least as large as `int`, and `long long` is at least as large as `long`. If you need a fixed size across platforms, you can use `int8_t`, `int32_t`, and similar types from the `cstdint` header, though it's not guaranteed that every platform will have those. Or make a custom type.

Comment: You forgot one point: The type determines the kind and range of values a variable of that type can have. Imo that’s the most important aspect of them all.